# How to get the last visible element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SHfz4/

Technically all those blue boxes are visible as in none are displayed as none so I can't use something like this:

`$('.row .inner .item:visible:last');`

Because that will give box 27 each time.

As you can see some boxes are visible and other's are not depending on the size of your view port, resizing will cause more boxes to go out of view or come into view.

I need a way to get the last visible item in a row. How to do this?

P.S. I have been snippets posted here on SO that show how to tell if an element is in view but some of those scripts were returning true even when they shouldn't and all of them required a specific element to be checked against, but my case requires me to just ask for the last and not specifically test a given element.

CSS:

```
.row { border: 1px solid red; height: 50px; overflow: hidden; }
.row .inner { width: 1000px; }
.row .inner .item { box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px blue; width: 50px; height: 50px; float: left; line-height: 50px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item item-1">1</div>
        <div class="item item-2">2</div>    
        <div class="item item-3">3</div>
        <div class="item item-4">4</div>
        <div class="item item-5">5</div>    
        <div class="item item-6">6</div>
        <div class="item item-7">7</div>
        <div class="item item-8">8</div>    
        <div class="item item-9">9</div>
        <div class="item item-10">10</div>
        <div class="item item-11">11</div>    
        <div class="item item-12">12</div>
        <div class="item item-13">13</div>
        <div class="item item-14">14</div>    
        <div class="item item-15">15</div>
        <div class="item item-16">16</div>
        <div class="item item-17">17</div>    
        <div class="item item-18">18</div>  
        <div class="item item-19">19</div>
        <div class="item item-20">20</div>    
        <div class="item item-21">21</div>
        <div class="item item-22">22</div>
        <div class="item item-23">23</div>    
        <div class="item item-24">24</div>
        <div class="item item-25">25</div>
        <div class="item item-26">26</div>    
        <div class="item item-27">27</div>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I need a way to get the last visible item in a row."_ The last completely visible item, or partially visible item?

Comment: Is the window & divs `width` fixed, or you want flexible with cenario?

Comment: Do you mean get the last item that is visible within the constraints of the container that a user can see??

Comment: Wouldn't `Math.floor($('.row').width()/50)` get the last fully visible and `Math.ceil($('.row').width()/50)` the last partially visible?

Comment: @Sergio no the window and div aren't fixed, they should be fluid, the inner div however has a fixed width to an arbitrarily high number (1000px) so that all divs float side by side.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SHfz4/4/ could be a solution

Comment: @TK123 Are the boxes in the container of varying widths or are the all the same?

Comment: @Sethen Maleno same, all 50px wide.

Comment: I think there are some jQuery plugins for detecting whether elements are in the viewport. Try googling for that.

Comment: Why is the simple division a partial answer? What isn't it giving you that you need?

Comment: @TK123 in this case you just need a simple algo to calculate how many items are visible depending own width and container width, should be enough

Comment: @TK123 Retrieve how big the actual container is and then do some math.

Comment: I like @A.Wolff solution.. I am running into a case where it doesn't work exactly right.  I also think it's a little too bulky for this situation.

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for this, it doesn't seem to work at all times though, see http://i.imgur.com/bHZ5lSn.png box 7 is partially visible but it says 6

Comment: @TK123 depending your definition of visible (completly or partially). In jsfiddle, it is using center point, you could wish to use top left point: http://jsfiddle.net/SHfz4/6/

Comment: @A.Wolff This is perfect, thank you so much. If you post this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: @TK123 see undefined's answer, so much better in your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this snippet do what you expect?

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^=item]')
    ,row = items[0].offsetParent
    ,rightBoundary = row.clientLeft+row.clientWidth
    ,bottomBoundary = row.clientTop+row.clientHeight
    ,found = null;

for (var i=0;i<items.length;i+=1){
    if (items[i].offsetLeft > rightBoundary || 
        items[i].offsetTop > bottomBoundary){
        found = items[i-1];
        break;
    }
}
// reports div.item item-17
```

See [**this fork**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/nTazB/) of your jsFiddle

[**edit**] added a check for [invisible] items *below* the first row of items, see the [**full screen version**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/nTazB/show) of the jsFiddle

Answer (score 2):

```
var timeout = '';

$(window).resize(function () {
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(function () {
       var $row = $('.row'),
           rWidth = $row.width(),
           $item = $row.find('.item').filter(function () {
               var $this = $(this),
                   l = $this.width() + $this.position().left;
               return l >= rWidth;
           }).first();
   }, 60);
}).resize();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EkA3K/